# Filter parsed JSON object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am making rest call and receving following JSON response:

```
{
    "issues": [{
            "id": "250271",
            "self": "KeyUrl1",
            "key": "Key-8622",
            "fields": {
                "attachment": [{
                        "self": "AttachmentUrl1",
                        "id": "106198",
                        "filename": "export.htm"
                    }
                ],
                "customfield_11041": "Test"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "250272",
            "self": "KeyUrl2",
            "key": "Key-8621",
            "fields": {
                "attachment": [{
                        "self": "AttachmentUrl2",
                        "id": "106199",
                        "filename": "lmn.htm"
                    }
                ],
                "customfield_11041": "Test"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

I parsed it using NewtonSoft Json to JObject.

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(response);
```

Further I am trying to filter such records where either attachment is missing or none of the attachments contain filename like "export".

Following is the code I have written, ideally it should result in just 1 record in the records object, however its returning both the objects.

```
var issues = jObject["issues"] as JArray;
var records = issues.Where(x => !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any() || !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any(y => y["filename"].Contains("export")));
```

Need help to figure out whats going wrong.

Here's fiddle link - https://dotnetfiddle.net/AVyIHr

Comment: For one thing, you can simplify this to just the latter condition - you're basically saying you want issues that don't have an attachment containing "export". An issue with *no* attachments satisfies that condition as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `Contains("export")` on the result of `y["filename"]`, which isn't a string - it's a `JToken`. You need to convert to a string first, to use the form of `Contains` that you're expecting.

Additionally, you can get rid of the first condition - an issue with *no* attachments doesn't have any attachments with "export" filename anyway.

That leaves this:

```
var records = issues
    .Where(x => !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any(y => ((string) y["filename"]).Contains("export")))
    .ToList();
```

You may well find it's simpler to deserialize to a class, however - that will reduce the risk of typos *and* the risk of this sort of conversion error. If you deserialized to a `List<Issue>` you'd have a condition of:

```
x => !x.Fields.Attachments.Any(y => y.Filename.Contains("export"))
```

... which I think is rather cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
var records = issues.Where(x => !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any() || !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any(y => y["filename"].ToString().Contains("export"))).ToList();
```

Add `.ToString()` will resolve the issue.

Comment: What if `filename` is `null` ?

Comment: `var records = issues.Where(x => !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any() || !x["fields"]["attachment"].Any(y => y["filename"] != null && y["filename"].ToString().Contains("export"))).ToList();`

add `y["filename"] != null &&`